# algorithm that can determine for every regular language L

Tags: computability, fl.formal-languages, regular-language

can you please tell me how can I show that there exists an algorithm that can determine for every regular language L, whether or not |L| ≥ 5

Comment: Regular language, not computer language? And if the latter: please explain some more then, so we can determine on which site this question might fit better.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.